Added kpfonts to the file but won't produce a pdf. Why?
I just changed computer to work on TeXstudio on Ubuntu. I installed the full TeXlive and all the packages I usually use seem to work, except for a font one : kpfonts.
The following script does not produce a pdf file
\documentclass[english,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
bonjour
\end{document}

but the following error

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 jkpmn8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for jkpmn8r. mktexpk: perhaps jkpmn8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
Processus terminé avec une ou plusieurs erreurs

If I understood correctly I am supposed to updmap in some smart way to indicate the map to the fonts (whatever this means). I tried running updmap-sys but it told me

Directory "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap" isn't writable:  at /usr/bin/updmap line 1482

so I tried updmap-user but now I am regretting my choice and things still do not work. And I am too much of an Ubuntu beginner not to break things further on my own.
Thus I have 2 questions : how do I finally change that damn font and how do I undo what I changed ?
EDIT :
Here is the log TeXstudio produces. I translated the bits in french (as my editor is setted in french).
Running process : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 jkpmn8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for jkpmn8r. mktexpk: perhaps jkpmn8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
Process completed with one or more mistakes

EDIT 2 :
I added the content of the log file.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.10.23)  26 OCT 2024 16:05 entering extended mode  restricted \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled.
**document.tex (./document.tex LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2024-01-22> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) \c@part=\count187 \c@section=\count188 \c@subsection=\count189 \c@subsubsection=\count190 \c@paragraph=\count191 \c@subparagraph=\count192 \c@figure=\count193 \c@table=\count194 \abovecaptionskip=\skip48 \belowcaptionskip=\skip49 \bibindent=\dimen140 ) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kpfonts/kpfonts.sty Package: kpfonts  2023/01/18 v3.35

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests ) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features \@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option. (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions \@emptytoks=\toks17 \ex@=\dimen141 )) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols \pmbraise@=\dimen142 ) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names ) \inf@bad=\count195 LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234. \uproot@=\count196 \leftroot@=\count197 LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line
399. LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410. \classnum@=\count198 \DOTSCASE@=\count199 LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496. LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line
499. LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620. \Mathstrutbox@=\box51 \strutbox@=\box52 LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722. LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723. LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724. LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725. \big@size=\dimen143 LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744. \macc@depth=\count266 LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905. LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910. LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940. LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970. LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971. \c@MaxMatrixCols=\count267 \dotsspace@=\muskip16 \c@parentequation=\count268 \dspbrk@lvl=\count269 \tag@help=\toks18 \row@=\count270 \column@=\count271 \maxfields@=\count272 \andhelp@=\toks19 \eqnshift@=\dimen144 \alignsep@=\dimen145 \tagshift@=\dimen146 \tagwidth@=\dimen147 \totwidth@=\dimen148 \lineht@=\dimen149 \@envbody=\toks20 \multlinegap=\skip51 \multlinetaggap=\skip52 \mathdisplay@stack=\toks21 LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line
2953. LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954. ) \c@mv@rm=\count273 \c@mv@boldrm=\count274 \c@mv@sf=\count275 \c@mv@boldsf=\count276 LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 377. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/jkp/m/n on input line 377. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold' (Font)           OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/jkp/m/n on input line 377. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `rm' (Font)             OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/jkp/m/n on input line 377. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `boldrm' (Font)         OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/jkp/m/n on input line 377. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `sf' (Font)             OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/jkp/m/n on input line 377. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `boldsf' (Font)         OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/jkp/m/n on input line 377. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold' (Font)           OT1/jkp/m/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 378. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `rm' (Font)             OT1/jkp/m/n --> OT1/jkp/m/n on input line 380. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `boldrm' (Font)         OT1/jkp/m/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 381. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `sf' (Font)             OT1/jkp/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/m/n on input line 382. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `boldsf' (Font)         OT1/jkp/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/b/n on input line 383. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathrm on input line 387. LaTeX Font Info:  Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold' (Font)           OT1/jkp/m/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 388. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `rm' (Font)             OT1/jkp/m/n --> OT1/jkp/m/n on input line 389. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `boldrm' (Font)         OT1/jkp/m/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 390. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `sf' (Font)             OT1/jkp/m/n --> OT1/jkp/m/n on input line 391. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `boldsf' (Font)         OT1/jkp/m/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 392. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 401. LaTeX Font Info:  Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal' (Font)         OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 401. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold' (Font)           OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 401. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `rm' (Font)             OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 401. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `boldrm' (Font)         OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 401. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `sf' (Font)             OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 401. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `boldsf' (Font)         OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 401. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold' (Font)           OT1/jkp/b/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 402. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `rm' (Font)             OT1/jkp/b/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 404. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `boldrm' (Font)         OT1/jkp/b/n --> OT1/jkp/b/n on input line 405. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `sf' (Font)             OT1/jkp/b/n --> OT1/jkpss/b/n on input line 406. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `boldsf' (Font)         OT1/jkp/b/n --> OT1/jkpss/b/n on input line 407. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 413. LaTeX Font Info:  Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal' (Font)         OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/jkp/m/it on input line 413. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold' (Font)           OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/jkp/m/it on input line 413. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `rm' (Font)             OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/jkp/m/it on input line 413. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `boldrm' (Font)         OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/jkp/m/it on input line 413. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `sf' (Font)             OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/jkp/m/it on input line 413. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `boldsf' (Font)         OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/jkp/m/it on input line 413. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold' (Font)           OT1/jkp/m/it --> OT1/jkp/b/it on input line 414. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `rm' (Font)             OT1/jkp/m/it --> OT1/jkp/m/it on input line 416. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `boldrm' (Font)         OT1/jkp/m/it --> OT1/jkp/b/it on input line 417. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `sf' (Font)             OT1/jkp/m/it --> OT1/jkpss/m/it on input line 418. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `boldsf' (Font)         OT1/jkp/m/it --> OT1/jkpss/b/it on input line 419. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathsf on input line 424. LaTeX Font Info:  Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal' (Font)         OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/m/n on input line 424. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold' (Font)           OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/jkpss/m/n on input line 424. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `rm' (Font)             OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/m/n on input line 424. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `boldrm' (Font)         OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/m/n on input line 424. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `sf' (Font)             OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/m/n on input line 424. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `boldsf' (Font)         OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/m/n on input line 424. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold' (Font)           OT1/jkpss/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/b/n on input line 425. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `rm' (Font)             OT1/jkpss/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/m/n on input line 426. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `boldrm' (Font)         OT1/jkpss/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/b/n on input line 427. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `sf' (Font)             OT1/jkpss/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/m/n on input line 428. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `boldsf' (Font)         OT1/jkpss/m/n --> OT1/jkpss/b/n on input line 429. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathtt on input line 433. LaTeX Font Info:  Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal' (Font)         OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/jkptt/m/n on input line 433. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold' (Font)           OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/jkptt/m/n on input line 433. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `rm' (Font)             OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/jkptt/m/n on input line 433. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `boldrm' (Font)         OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/jkptt/m/n on input line 433. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `sf' (Font)             OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/jkptt/m/n on input line 433. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `boldsf' (Font)         OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/jkptt/m/n on input line 433. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold' (Font)           OT1/jkptt/m/n --> OT1/jkptt/b/n on input line 434. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `rm' (Font)             OT1/jkptt/m/n --> OT1/jkptt/m/n on input line 435. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `boldrm' (Font)         OT1/jkptt/m/n --> OT1/jkptt/b/n on input line 436. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `sf' (Font)             OT1/jkptt/m/n --> OT1/jkptt/m/n on input line 437. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `boldsf' (Font)         OT1/jkptt/m/n --> OT1/jkptt/b/n on input line 438. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 446. LaTeX Font Info:  Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal' (Font)           OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/jkp/m/it on input line 446. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold' (Font)             OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/jkp/m/it on input line 446. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `rm' (Font)               OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/jkp/m/it on input line 446. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `boldrm' (Font)           OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/jkp/m/it on input line 446. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `sf' (Font)               OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/jkp/m/it on input line 446. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `boldsf' (Font)           OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/jkp/m/it on input line 446. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold' (Font)             OML/jkp/m/it --> OML/jkp/bx/it on input line 447. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `rm' (Font)               OML/jkp/m/it --> OML/jkp/m/it on input line 449. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `boldrm' (Font)           OML/jkp/m/it --> OML/jkp/bx/it on input line 450. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `sf' (Font)               OML/jkp/m/it --> OML/jkpss/m/it on input line 451. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `boldsf' (Font)           OML/jkp/m/it --> OML/jkpss/bx/it on input line 452. \symlettersA=\mathgroup4 LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lettersA' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/jkpmia/m/it --> U/jkpmia/bx/it on input line 462. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lettersA' in version `rm' (Font)                  U/jkpmia/m/it --> U/jkpmia/m/it on input line 464. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lettersA' in version `boldrm' (Font)          U/jkpmia/m/it --> U/jkpmia/bx/it on input line 465. LaTeX Font Info:   Overwriting symbol font `lettersA' in version `sf' (Font)              U/jkpmia/m/it --> U/jkpssmia/m/it on input line 466. LaTeX Font Info:  Overwriting symbol font `lettersA' in version `boldsf' (Font)          U/jkpmia/m/it --> U/jkpssmia/bx/it on input line 467. LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 479. LaTeX Font Info:  Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal' (Font)           OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/jkp/m/n on input line 479. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold' (Font)             OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/jkp/m/n on input line 479. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `rm' (Font)               OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/jkp/m/n on input line 479. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `boldrm' (Font)           OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/jkp/m/n on input line 479. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `sf' (Font)               OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/jkp/m/n on input line 479. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `boldsf' (Font)           OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/jkp/m/n on input line 479. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold' (Font)             OMS/jkp/m/n --> OMS/jkp/bx/n on input line 480. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `rm' (Font)               OMS/jkp/m/n --> OMS/jkp/m/n on input line 482. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `boldrm' (Font)           OMS/jkp/m/n --> OMS/jkp/bx/n on input line 483. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `sf' (Font)               OMS/jkp/m/n --> OMS/jkp/m/n on input line 484. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `boldsf' (Font)           OMS/jkp/m/n --> OMS/jkp/bx/n on input line 485. \symAMSa=\mathgroup5 LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSa' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/jkpsya/m/n --> U/jkpsya/bx/n on input line
499. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSa' in version `rm' (Font)                  U/jkpsya/m/n --> U/jkpsya/m/n on input line 500. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSa' in version `boldrm' (Font)                  U/jkpsya/m/n --> U/jkpsya/bx/n on input line 501. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSa' in version `sf' (Font)                  U/jkpsya/m/n --> U/jkpsya/m/n on input line 502. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSa' in version `boldsf' (Font)              U/jkpsya/m/n --> U/jkpsya/bx/n on input line 503. \symAMSb=\mathgroup6 LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSb' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/jkpsyb/m/n --> U/jkpsyb/bx/n on input line
552. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSb' in version `rm' (Font)                  U/jkpsyb/m/n --> U/jkpsyb/m/n on input line 553. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSb' in version `boldrm' (Font)                  U/jkpsyb/m/n --> U/jkpsyb/bx/n on input line 554. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSb' in version `sf' (Font)                  U/jkpsyb/m/n --> U/jkpsssyb/m/n on input line 555. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSb' in version `boldsf' (Font)              U/jkpsyb/m/n --> U/jkpsssyb/bx/n on input line 556. \symsymbolsC=\mathgroup7 LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbolsC' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/jkpsyc/m/n --> U/jkpsyc/bx/n on input line 572. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbolsC' in version `rm' (Font)                  U/jkpsyc/m/n --> U/jkpsyc/m/n on input line 574. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbolsC' in version `boldrm' (Font)          U/jkpsyc/m/n --> U/jkpsyc/bx/n on input line 575. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbolsC' in version `sf' (Font)              U/jkpsyc/m/n --> U/jkpsyc/m/n on input line 576. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbolsC' in version `boldsf' (Font)          U/jkpsyc/m/n --> U/jkpsyc/bx/n on input line 577. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathscr' in version `bold' (Font)          U/jkpsyd/m/n --> U/jkpsyd/bx/n on input line 606. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathscr' in version `rm' (Font)            U/jkpsyd/m/n --> U/jkpsyd/m/n on input line 608. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathscr' in version `boldrm' (Font)        U/jkpsyd/m/n --> U/jkpsyd/bx/n on input line 609. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathscr' in version `sf' (Font)            U/jkpsyd/m/n --> U/jkpsyd/m/n on input line 610. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathscr' in version `boldsf' (Font)        U/jkpsyd/m/n --> U/jkpsyd/bx/n on input line 611. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 621. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal' (Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/jkp/m/n on input line
621. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold' (Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/jkp/m/n on input line 621. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `rm' (Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n
--> OMX/jkp/m/n on input line 621. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `boldrm' (Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/jkp/m/n on input line 621. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `sf' (Font)          OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/jkp/m/n on input line 621. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `boldsf' (Font)      OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/jkp/m/n on input line 621. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold' (Font)        OMX/jkp/m/n --> OMX/jkp/bx/n on input line 622. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `rm' (Font)          OMX/jkp/m/n --> OMX/jkp/m/n on input line 624. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `boldrm' (Font)      OMX/jkp/m/n --> OMX/jkp/bx/n on input line 625. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `sf' (Font)          OMX/jkp/m/n --> OMX/jkpss/m/n on input line 626. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `boldsf' (Font)      OMX/jkp/m/n --> OMX/jkpss/bx/n on input line 627. \symlargesymbolsA=\mathgroup8 LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbolsA' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/jkpexa/m/n --> U/jkpexa/bx/n on input line 638. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbolsA' in version `rm' (Font)         U/jkpexa/m/n --> U/jkpexa/m/n on input line 640. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbolsA' in version `boldrm'

(Font)                  U/jkpexa/m/n --> U/jkpexa/bx/n on input line
641. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbolsA' in version `sf' (Font)                  U/jkpexa/m/n --> U/jkpexa/m/n on input line 642. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbolsA' in version `boldsf'

(Font)                  U/jkpexa/m/n --> U/jkpexa/bx/n on input line
643. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 963. LaTeX Info: Redefining \not on input line 1603. ) LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+jkp on input line 6 .

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kpfonts/ot1jkp.fd File: ot1jkp.fd 2007/08/30 Fontinst v1.928 font definitions for OT1/jkp. ) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-01-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX) \l__color_backend_stack_int=\count277 \l__pdf_internal_box=\box53 )

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [english].

(./document.aux) \openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/jkp/m/it on input line
6. LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OML+jkp on input line 6 .  (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kpfonts/omljkp.fd File: omljkp.fd 2006/08/15 v1.0 ) LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line
6. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/jkp/m/n on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMS+jkp on input line 6 .

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kpfonts/omsjkp.fd File: omsjkp.fd 2006/08/15 v1.0 ) LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line
6. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/jkp/m/n on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMX+jkp on input line 6 .

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kpfonts/omxjkp.fd File: omxjkp.fd 2006/08/15 v1.0 ) LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line
6. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/jkpexa/m/n on input line 6. LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+jkpexa on input line 
6.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kpfonts/ujkpexa.fd File: ujkpexa.fd 2006/08/15 v1.0 ) LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.  [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./document.aux) 
*********** LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2024-01-22>  ***********  )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  2699 strings out of 474222  34450 string characters out of 5748732  1922975 words of memory out of 5000000  24993 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000  559847 words of font info for 39 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  71i,5n,79p,258b,113s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

!pdfTeX error: /usr/bin/pdflatex (file jkpmn8r): Font jkpmn8r at 600 not found  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


you've added messages from texstudio, but the log file pdflatex produces will give more information. this should be in the same directory as your .tex filebut will have the extensionlograther thantex`. can you add that, too, please?

I don't see how to include a file into my original post. Do you mean copying the content of the log file ? This is a lot of text.

it should not be that much to add the log you get when you try to compile the example you posted. and, yes, you have to copy-paste the content. there's no way to attach files ;).

Ok I am sorry to only come back now. I did add the content of the log file. I hope this is readable for you because it does not look clear to me at all. Thanks for your help.

@20-sided-dice Could you copy&paste your log file again as a code block so that line breaks are preserved? I tried to remove the block quote and replace it with a code block, but unfortunately this didn't bring back line breaks.

what does jkpmn8r.tfm give? I would try reinstalling whichever package provides kpfonts on debian. if that doesn't work, it may be a debian packaging bug. (I don't have debian to test.)

Never run updmap --user unless you understand and are confident you can deal with the consequences. see here. The answer includes instructions for undoing the damage you may have done. Do not be tempted to skip this step1.
You are using Ubuntu's TeX Live, so you should install the fonts the same way you installed TeX Live e.g. using apt or whichever package manager you normally use.
On my system, I would need to install texlive-fontsextra to get kpfonts, but the package may be named differently on Ubuntu. I found the name by searching my distro's package database for kpfonts i.e. pacman -Ss kpfonts returned texlive-fontsextra. On Ubuntu, the package seems to be called texlive-fonts-extra, so that's what you need to install.
You should not need to run updmap manually. apt should take care of that for you. Provided you clean up any mess resulting from your use of updmap --user. Failure to do this may undermine what apt does, which is why I said you should not skip the first step.
Even if it works now without cleanup, cleaning up will prevent the problems you'll inevitably run into sooner or later otherwise.
1You can also follow the link to TeX Live's page on this topic, but note that directories etc. will differ on Ubuntu because Linux distros install TeX Live into a different location from the one used by the upstream installer.

Ok here what I did right now with your indications. I ran "mv -n $(dirname $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFVAR)) $(dirname $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFVAR)).bkup" from the webpage you indicated me (no idea if it is the good command I am just following you) then ran "apt install texlive-fonts-extra". But the terminal tells me there are some lock files I can not open. Apparently I need some superuser powers. Even if I am an administrator ?

@20-sided-dice don't you usually use sudo apt install ...?

Absolutely not. I tried expressing that I am an absolute beginner with Ubuntu.

@20-sided-dice unless you have an extremely unusual (and probably dodgy) setup, you need root privileges to install or remove software managed by apt. so try sudo apt install ....

Ok adding the "sudo" in front of it made it kinda work. The terminal is telling me it did everything necessary and that it was already the most recent version. The problem being that I still can not produce a pdf file.

would need to see the log. can you edit your question to include it? @20-sided-dice

Ok. I added the log.
